# Android in-app products not appearing in Play Store or app

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I have created an app with in-app products. I've added the licensing key and billing permission in my app and created in-app products in the developer console. The products are active and I've built an alpha build which I've published and I can now see it and download it in the Google Play Store with one of the test accounts. 
Only problem is I can't get the in-app products! They're not showing up in the Play Store (which I assume they should). I get successful connection results in the app, but I don't get any products there either.

Where can I have gone wrong?

I know this is very unspecific, but I've looked through so many guides that I just don't know where to search anymore, so any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out waiting a bit longer did the trick! A bit confusing that the products and the build got published at different times.

The build got published after about 2 hours but the products didn't show up until the next day.

Comment: Same situation. Waited 5h since alpha got published and SKU not appearing yet. In-App was created and active yesterday. Let's see if tomorrow it updates according to your experience.

Answer (score 0):

Try publishing your app in alpha or beta. They have changed the way of doing tests and now this is required.

Comment: I've done this and the alpha is now shown in the Play Store. But as I said, the in-app purchases are not listed with it.