# How to release an app to Alpha group before any release to the public (playstore)?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I believe this question would be a repeat of this question:

[Android in-app products not appearing in Play Store or app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190027/android-in-app-products-not-appearing-in-play-store-or-app)

but that question does not answer my question clear enough, so I'm asking again.

I have an app that I would like to test the in app payment feature, and I have read that in app products will only be available once the app has been published to at least beta or alpha.

I want to publish the app to beta or alpha, but it seems like in order to get a opt-in URL, you need at least one version of the app released to the public(playstore), if I am not wrong, and I do not want to do this as the app is still in development.

Is there a way to do a alpha testing before releasing no versions of the app to the playstore?

Here is a screen shot of my google play console:
[image]

Edited: 
Why am I not seeing a opt-in URL here?

[image]

Comment: Yes, add tester Gmail id to test your app for payment purpose

Comment: @Sniffer Thank you for the quick response! I have added myself as a tester, but I have not got any emails, or I do not see a opt-in link in the manage tester section of my beta testing tab as shown in my edited question.

Comment: Please look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2IbTSYNzA)

Comment: First you have to upload your apk on `Alpha` and submit for review/rollout. After wait a while for google review. Once your app is reviewed by google then you can able to see your opt-in URL link here.

Comment: @Sniffer I have watched the video, and in this video, the guy actually publishes the app to the public. I don't want to do that. I want to keep my app private for the moment, and test payments.

Comment: @Ninja I have waited for an hour and a half. Does it usually take this long?

Comment: Maye be it will take time when you are uploading first time apk on any of the mode. After next version will be live within 30 to 40 mins if you upload.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So it turns out that it takes like 2, 3 days until the alpha or beta testing goes live. The official documentation does not say anything about it, and it actually makes it sound like it happens instantly.

Comment: Aha! Is this 2-3 days after you find and click the `Send for review` button hidden in (IIRC) the "Publishing overview" section of the Console and also accept the Terms & Conditions in the unmentioned `Internal app sharing` section of the Console?

Answer (score 1):

You'll receive an update to the for **your app** if you already have it installed on your device.

If you don't have **your app** installed, download it on Google Play.

**Note: It can take a while for you to receive the update.**

You can leave the testing program at any time. You can switch to the public version of the app if that's available.
To switch to the public version:

```
Uninstall the testing version.
Install the public version on Google Play.
```

**Note: It can take up to a few hours before you can download the app's public version.**

Comment: That's that thing. I don't want to publish my app to the public. I want to test the payment feature first, but I am not able to even do that, because the play store is not giving me a opt-in link to down load the app.

Answer (score 1):

For current version Of Google Play Console:

```
 Release > Testing > Closed Testing > Alpha

  1. Click On Testing (Option Under Release) 
  2. Select Closed Testing.
  3. Select Alpha Track.
  4. Upload Your app Bundle or Apk.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps on your Console:**

1) Complete store listing, pricing & distribution, content rating

2) Upload your apk and release to alpha

3) Complete in-app products (Requires billing permission from manifest)

4) By opt-in url you can test the application

Comment: I have completed the first three steps, but the opt-in URL does not show up

Comment: In your question you have uploaded the apk in beta and alpha.Try to upload and release in any one platform

Comment: Here is your mistake on your last image in ur question u should choose **closed alpha/beta testing** @dshukertjr