# When newly added in-app SKU becomes available to billingclient 2.0.1 after making it active in Play console?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I couldn't find this specific question in SO. What I find is related to first time in-app setup.

However in my case the app is in production for several years. 
It has SKU A,B,C active and available for testing in **release builds that aren't even published to play**.

Now I added a new SKU "D". What needs to happen so that it becomes available for testing?

Yesterday I created a new in-app product, and made it **active** on google play console. Now it's not clear to me **when billingclient will receive this update from play services**.

From what I read [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing) is that the new app needs to be published to either open or closed testing track.

I have also done that. Published on Alpha track 5h ago. Downloaded through play store via testing link (opt-in done with testing google account). New SKU still not appearing in logs.

I double checked all the requirements found [here](https://medium.com/bleeding-edge/testing-in-app-purchases-on-android-a6de74f78878) (recap section below).

I'm using `com.android.billingclient:billing:2.0.1` plus the setup with Repository and LiveData as shown in [TrivialDriveKotlin](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDriveKotlin/app/src/main/java/com/kotlin/trivialdrive/billingrepo/BillingRepository.kt)

Found [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190027/android-in-app-products-not-appearing-in-play-store-or-app) but not same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me so much time to spot the mistake, my mistake.

The problem lies in the super complicated setup of [TrivialDriveKotlin](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDriveKotlin/app/src/main/java/com/kotlin/trivialdrive/billingrepo/BillingRepository.kt) sample with Room, lots of DAOs and LiveData.

The initial understanding of the sample can take some hours but then you get your code working and forget about it.

When you come back to add new SKU, you need to add it in several places in all this classes:

- Entitlements.kt
- EntitlementsDao.kt
- LocalBillingDb.kt
- BillingRepository.kt
- BillingViewModel.kt

Having so many places that are affected, is easy to forget one of them. In my case I forgot to add it to **INAPP_SKUS** list which was used in `querySkuDetails` call.

Definitely worth considering a refactor to unify.